# Ubuntu Server 10.10 - password getting reset

Tags: ubuntu, password-reset

We are using Unbuntu Server 10.10 (64 bit) and have deployed number of instances in our network.

Servers work normally for a day or two and after that the super user is not able to login. Server works normally, services can be accessed - but no user can login from shell. We have to recover the password via password recovery procedure. This is observed on all the deployed instances.

Has anyone faced similar issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you doing package updates in between ? Anything affecting "sudo" otherwise or do you use the root account to "su -" to ?

Comment: We are not doing any package updates. We are not using root account - any previliged activity is executed using sudo only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a fan of sudo. You could run `passwd root` on one box and eliminate `sudo` to see if that helps. What does `/var/log/auth.log` say at the times the is access denied ?

Do you have any home made scripts running on Cron that change permission on `/etc` by accident ?

Comment: We are not having any home made scripts. It is pretty simple implementation - vanilla flavored Ubuntu Server 10.10 and we run Tomcat server on that - just install Java and Tomcat

Comment: Any time-limited logins with PAM ? You could check "/etc/pam.d/" files. Hopefully "var/log/auth.log" will shed some light.

Comment: Thanks for the input, we had a look at /var/log/auth.log and found that there was attack on the server from external systems. Eventually the password of our system was not strong enough - and administrators were using same password for backup account. The auth.log revealed that certain external IPs had tried logging in with default common accounts like Oracle/ftptest/student etc. We have hardened the server passwords and now monitoring the same.

Comment: Glad you got to the bottom of it.